# Looking for a way to simplify multiple gsub lines

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is a solution that I am using to replace all instances of `<p><ol>`,`<p><ul>` to `<ol>` and `<ul>` respectively.

```
    text = text.gsub("<p><ol>","<ol>")
    text = text.gsub("<p><ul>","<ul>")
    text = text.gsub("<p><p>","<p>")
    text = text.gsub("</ol>","</ol><p>")
    text = text.gsub("</ul>","</ul><p>")
```

I am trying to figure out a way to simplify those lines using regex, or any other ways that works for Rails to do those lines. Am not great in regex or know the limitations so any help would be great

Comment: You are asking for a better way to solve a problem without telling us what the problem is. You need to begin by stating the problem, preferably with a small example, then say one solution is to use the following five `gsub` statements sequentially. Lastly, after for suggested improvements.

Comment: Sorry about that. Will edit the question

Comment: No problem. Sometimes askers get sidetracked with their attempted solution, forgetting that readers may not understand what they are trying to do.

Comment: If your problem is what you're stating it is, then this is the best way to do it. Most clear in intension. Adding regexes to the mix would make it harder to read and understand and possibly not even faster. Why is the current code bad? If you're worried about repeating `.gsub`, you could extract your replacements to a hash or other data structure and iterate over it.